# How does Stack Overflow logout work?

Tags: discussion, support, logout, implementation

I just want to **logout** from Stack Overflow. I got below screen.

Now I have a doubt, though -  there is one checkbox with text "log out on all devices". I do not understand what this stands for?

Does it means this will invalidate all the apps `access_token` that I implemented in my personal Stack Overflow Android App by using [Authentication OAuth 2.0](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)?

Or it just logout from all the Stack Overflow child sites of the Desktop Broswer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will invalidate the access token for the devices, so you should be logged out on your desktop, the SE official app, any app you developed yourself, etc.

Comment: Thanks let me try this.

Comment: Strange thing happened here when i logout from web and still my all app `access_tokens` are still active.